# LocalDateTime timezone works, while LocalTime does not

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, datetime, java-time

I have an Spring Boot application with Hibernate. Server timezone is UTC. I need to use Europe/London with DST (Daylight Saving Time). I set up on start up:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
```

And connection with MySQL

```
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=Europe/London
    name:
    username: ****
    password: ****
    hikari:
        data-source-properties:
            cachePrepStmts: true
            prepStmtCacheSize: 250
            prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
            useServerPrepStmts: true
            hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: Europe/London
```

I don't want to change my time to UTC. I need to stay with DST and that's all. My application is for UK only, so Europe/London is good enough.

The problem is when I have LocalDateTime e.g.: 31.07.2017 14:00 and store it to database, then I have exactly same entry in DB. But when I store LocalTime (alone) at 14:00, then it's saved in database as 13:00. Why the time it's converted behind the scene?

**UPDATE:**

After more debugging (added two lines to application.properties):

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```

I see that Hibernate does not convert time. It sent 14:00 but MySQL convert it to 13:00. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

According to the  [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#now--), `LocalTime.now()` should check the current `TimeZone`. I worked only once with Hibernate and was thoroughly confused with the rules and order in which things were done (my bad!). I would suggest that you use `LocalTime now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))`. Hence, you would become independent of everything else.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @rlinden. It's look like MySQL change values alone. I have connection parameter serverTimezone=Europe/London for force use Europe/London and it works for DATETIME but doesn't for TIME. I mean, MySQL do nothing with DATETIME but change value in TIME field. I need Europe/London for "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" etc.